# Unable to find dependency on pre-build aplication, Installer Visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, system.text.json

I have a project that references libreries with netstandar 2.0. When the project compile there are not problems, but when I try create an installer is just not working. Well, the file is created but the application does not work properly, especifically with System.Text.Json. Firts the compile output showed something like "unable to find System.Text.Json Version 5.0.0.0" and others, well this message is no longer showed but persist other problems and the application does not work anyway, mainly when try to serealize-deserealize objects with System.Text.Json.

Here these message that its getting[image: Unable to find dependecy]

Comment: What is target framework about your current project, is .net core or .net framework? Based on my test, I I used the .net core app to reference the .netstandard 2.0 dll, there is no errors for me and I can run the code successfully. Also, If possible, you could provide a sample code about your Library and your project.

Comment: Was targeting to .NET Framework 4.7, now I change to .NET Core 3 and it works

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could  click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, the solution is that we need to change the target framework to .NET Core3.1 or later version.